# Sidebar going outside of wrap?

Tags: css, text, css-float, sidebar

This is the code, you can see what is wrong easily.

```css
#wrap {
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    background: #CCC;
}
#sidebar {
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    border: outset; 
    float: right;
    overflow: auto;
}
#content {
    border: outset;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">  
    <div id="sidebar">Some text here</div>
    <div id="content">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

I have a sneaky suspicion that it has to do with float: right, but I can't get the sidebar to stay on the right side without it.

I want the wrap to expand to the height of whatever is inside it, which is why I set height: auto but it's not working, please help.

Comment: Sorry It wouldn't let me post the jsfiddle link for some reason...edited.

Comment: You are supposed to reduce your code to _only_ what is required to reproduce the issue. Since you already have a sneaking suspicion, this is a great tool to tell you which parts to remove first.

Comment: I have already gone through everything I know how to do.....nothing has worked obviously which is why I am here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css proprty to this ID

```
#content{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Humble.Rumble, That fixed it. =)

Dunno why I have -4 votes on this question though.....Consider it solved!